# Amazon AWS EC2 usage

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have two questions on Amazon AWS EC2 usage computation:

If I installed a packaged AMI that is fedora core 5, tomcat mysql based and configure it to point to my subdomain demo.mydomain.com, I am interested in finding out how computational hours are calculated. The application that I am publishing is not really mission critical, more towards a demo for a web based tutorial that I am hosting to showcase my application development portfolio. Therefore, it makes sense for me not to invest in a full blown remote virtual dedicated server or something similar.

Say, in a 24 hour window:

- 0000 (hours) - Accessed by one user for 15 mins
- 0100 (hours) - Not accessed
- 0200 (hours) - Not accessed
- 0300 (hours) - Accessed by one user for 30 mins
- .
- .
- .
- 1300 (hours) - Not accessed
- 1400 (hours) - Accessed by one user for 15 mins
- .
- .
- .
- 2200 (hours) - Accessed by four users for 60 mins
- 2300 (hours) - Accessed by eight users for 60 mins
- 2400 (hours) - Not accessed

**Total: 180 mins (3 hours)**

Assuming that the average use is consistent based on the above hours for 30 days (to get a monthly total).

**30days x 3 hours = 180 hours (per month)**

Here are my questions:

1. Am I billed for the time that the service is not accessed although the web application is available online?
2. Are the charges based on per block hour used or per minute based used mileage?
   i.e 0000 hours, the service used was for 15 minutes, am I getting charged for the rest of 45 minutes?

Would anyone be able to advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

> Pricing is per instance-hour consumed for each instance type, from the time an instance is launched until it is terminated. Each partial instance-hour consumed will be billed as a full hour.

http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/

Comment: If two users users connect to the service for 15 minutes does it count as 15 minutes or 30minutes?

Comment: Bill will be generated based on how many hours instance is running. It doesn't matter weather it is a single user connected to the instance or a million.